# colab read local file

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

I am trying to read a local file which I uploaded to colab:

```
from google.colab import files
uploaded = files.upload()
```

I upload the file and I can see it. If I try to read the file, I get an error message:

```
data = open('test.txt', 'r')
```

> TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
>  in ()
> ----> 1 data = open('test.csv', 'r') TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable

I am using Chrome Version 102.0.5005.115.

Comment: Apparently, `open` is somehow a tuple, not the built-in `open` function

Comment: It's used to work before, very strange...

Comment: @honeymoon what changed? Do you have a line like `open = ...` somewhere? Or a `from module import *` that could contain something called `open`?